# JavaScript runtime error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns 128-128 [&] in

Tags: angularjs

I'm passing a query string to a function, which gets $compiled that opens a new window.
I get the following error

```
JavaScript runtime error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: 
    Unexpected next character  at columns 128-128 [&]
```

```
var url = 'http://.....?&filename=123.doc&user=Bob'
var html = <a href='#' ng-click='OpenUrl(" + url + ")'>MY LINK </a>"
var link =  $compile(html)($scope)
```

the function just opens a new window.  It doesn't seem to like the '&'

I'm **$compiling** the URL and expression so it can be used in an **ng-click**

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to understand what you are trying to do? you want to pass an URL as a paramter to ng-click?  and then, what is your goal: open a new browser-tab with this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you $compile the URL, I don't see why this would be needed. $compile in angular does not compile URLs, it compiles an HTML-String or a DOM-tree and compiles/links angular directives that are used in this HTML.

Is this solving your issue?

in the controller:

```
$scope.myUrl =  "http://... ";
```

in the HTML:

```
 <a ng-href="{{myUrl}}" target="_blank">blabla</a>
```

Comment: I need to fire an ng-click   when I do    <a href='#' ng-click ='GotoUrl('www.cnn.com')'>CNN</a>    I get  $santize:badparse

Comment: what is GotoUrl()? a JS function you wrote and put on $scope? if yes, please show it to us (edit your question)

Comment: the error you get simply says the that the string you pass to $compile is not valid HTML, which is true: you are passing it a URL without any tags. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sanitize/badparse   so, you should not $compile your URL